# Regex don't work in reactive form control

Tags: regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following regex for URL that require to start from http or https

`(http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]` that work very good for what I want (https://regexr.com/598hs)

But when I try to run it in angular validation, it doesn't work.

```
    this.form = fb.group({
      numberCode: ['', Validators.pattern(`(http:|https:)+[^s]+[w]/g`)]
    })
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-validation-lulnas

Why so ?

Comment: You're missing a backslash before both the `s` and the `w`. Try `(http:|https:)+[^\\s]+[\\w]`.

Comment: In addition to what @AhmedAbdelhameed said, the `/g` won't work if you write the expression like that. This should work `Validators.pattern(/(http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]/g)`

Comment: But from your stackblitz the validation is already working? I even copied the validation as such: Validators.pattern('(http:|https:)+[^\\s]+[\\w]') and its working.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try matching by this:

```
Validators.pattern(/^(http:|https:)+[^\s]+.+\.+.+$/)
```